# Microsoft Graph SDK PHP: CreateRequest not working

Tags: php, api

I am trying to use the Microsoft Graph SDK PHP.

I have simple directory with index.php and vendor (created exactly as requested in the related github project: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php).

My index.php file looks like:

```
require_once("./vendor/autoload.php");

use Microsoft\Graph\Graph;
use Microsoft\Graph\Model;

$accessToken = 'xxx'; // Here I would insert the access token

$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);

// Code that is not working:
$user = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/me")
   ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
   ->execute();

echo "Hello, I am $user->getGivenName() ";
```

The issue; **createRequest** is not working (the php file stop to be executed)... And I have no idea why, as I have just copied the sample code of the Github project.

What do I do wrong?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**: Apparently, any error in the access token will always make it crash. The code is therefore working.